# Replacement for "brethren" to refer to mostly female group

Tags: single-word-requests, kinship-terms, gender-positive

The word *brethren* would generally be used to refer to a group of people which have something making them an integrated unit. To exemplify my point in case:

> The Catholic Brethren...
>   My college brethren...

But, suppose if the population I was referring to was mostly female, the word *brethren* would seem inappropriate (considering its [definition](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/brethren) as "Fellow Christians or members of a *male* religious order"). To exemplify,

> my female Catholic Brethren...

isn't wrong, but just doesn't sound right.

Is there some word which would refer to a closely knitted *female* group?

Comment: As an alternative, a similar word pair is kinsmen/kinswomen.

Comment: sorority could fit, though it has a strong connotation of undergrad student group

Comment: I'll note that "circle" is often used in the US to refer to a group of female friends.

Answer (score 13):

People have used "sistern" for this. The first use I find in [Google books](https://books.google.com/books?id=AVgMAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA44&dq=sistern&hl=en&ei=T1KdTsnFEsLn0QHa3pXICQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CEwQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=sistern&f=false) is from 1739:

> That there were 20 Bretheren and Siſtern on their Bead Roll,

I suspect this plural was invented to serve as a parallel to "brethren"; I did not find it in the dictionaries I checked, and it is a much rarer word than "brethren".

UPDATE: as Unreason points out, I did not find it in dictionaries because it is currently spelled "sistren"; although until its recent revival around 1980, the spelling "sistern" was just as common (these are presumably also pronounced differently). Both forms are derived from the Middle English plural of "sister". [Google Ngram:](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sistern%2CSistern%2Csistren%2CSistren&year_start=1800&year_end=1987&corpus=0&smoothing=7)

[image: Ngram for sistern, sistren, Sistern, Sistren]

Comment: There is some mention here: http://oxforddictionaries.com/page/femininebrethren though spelling is *-ren*

Comment: The OED has 1533 citation (Thomas More).

Comment: Also, http://www.onelook.com/?w=sistren&ls=a

Comment: Wycliffe spelled it sitren (1382-1395). In spite of the ngram above I would assume *-ren* as correct due to *brethren* orders of magnitude more frequent than *brethern* and also *brethern* not in dictionaries.

Comment: @Unreason: Language changes. There are some dialects today that pronounce "children" as "childern". The plural "sistren" is historically correct, and clearly correct today, after its revival, but it may be that the only regions where this plural of "sister" survived into the 18th century spoke dialects in which it was pronounced "sistern". In this case, I would argue that "sistern" was correct at that time.

Comment: Ok (and to correct my mistake Wycliffe spelled it sistren)

Comment: As a practical matter I would be concerned that "sistern" could be confused with "cistern". (Edit: Oh, I see tchrist already pointed this out)

Answer (score 8):

Not to subtract from what others have said, but to add to it by providing more historical citations in context, here is what the *OED* has to say about ***sistren*** and ***sistern***. For some reason, these were uncommonly difficult to search for.  All are taken from entries that have not been updated since the *OED2*.

## On *sistren*

The first form, *sistren*, can be found in the citations for [**brother** *n.*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/23798), [**dean** *n.<sup>1</sup>*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/47724), [**sect** *n.<sup>1</sup>*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/174576), and [**sister** *n*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/180434).  Here’s the one from [**brother** *n.*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/23798) sense 3a:

> - *c*1449    R. Pecock *Repressor* (1860) 63    Thi Cristen britheren and sistren.

And here from sense 9b of [**dean** *n.<sup>1</sup>*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/47724):

> - 1389    in T. Smith & L. T. Smith *Eng. Gilds* (1870) 46    On Dene, for to warnyn alle þ<sup>e</sup> gild breþren and sistren.

Here from [**sect** *n.<sup>1</sup>*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/174576) sense 1b:

> - 1393    Langland *Piers Plowman* C. xvii. 293    Þoȝ men soȝt al sectes [*v.r.* þe sektis] of sistren & of breþeren.

Finally and most profitably from  [**sister**, *n.*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/180434), sense 1b, which is given as:

> - 1. b. In older forms of the plural.
>
>   In Old English the plural had either the same forms as the singular, or appears as *sweostra*, -*tru*, etc. These subsequently assumed the pl. -*n* of weak nouns, and gave the common Middle English forms *sustren*, *sostren*, *sistren*, etc. (cf. *brethren* (see **brother** *n*.)). In general literary use these were finally discarded about 1550 in favour of the pl. in -*s*, which is found as early as *c*1200.

And under which appear these relevant citations, all from the β citations of this sense. I also provide  older citations with alternate forms to show the (somewhat free) variation seen over time.

> - *c*950    *Lindisf. Gosp.* Mark vi. 3    Ahne suoestro [c1000 swustra, c1160 swustre] his her mið usic sint?
> - *c*1100    *Anglo-Saxon Chron.* (MS. D) ann. 1067,    Mid his modor & his twam sweostran.
> - [*c*1160    *Hatton Gosp.* Mark iii. 35    Se is min moder & min broðer & mine swustren.]
> - *c*1290    *S. Eng. Leg.* I. 435    Þat þou sum-ȝware þine sostrene do in-to ane nonnerie.
> - 1297    *R. Gloucester’s Chron.* (Rolls) 7560    His moder & is sostren tuo mid him sone he nom.
> - *c*1507    in T. Stapleton *Plumpton Corr.* (1839) 202,    I recommend me to you,‥and to all my brethren and sistren.
> - 1532  (1385)    *Usk’s Test. Loue* in *Wks. G. Chaucer* III. f. cccl<sup>v</sup>,    As susterne in vnite they accorden.
> - 1553    T. Wilson *Arte of Rhetorique* 30 b,    You have other parentes, other brethren, sisterne, and nephewes.
> - 1580    in J. Raine *Wills & Inventories N. Counties Eng.* (1835) I. 432,    I will that all the goodes be devyded equallye amongeste my Brethren and systeringe childringe.
> - 1859    J. R. Bartlett *Dict. Americanisms* (ed. 2),    *Sistern*, for sisters. A vulgar pronunciation sometimes heard from uneducated preachers at the West.

Notice how in the final citation, from American linguist John Russell Bartlett (1808–1886), that *sistern* is by then  considered vulgar and uneducated.

The form occurs again in this citation from  sense 3a:

> - 1482    in *Eng. Hist. Rev.* XXV. 122    Y<sup>e</sup> kepar of oure y<sup>e</sup> sistrenes librarie.

Then several times again in citations from sense 3b, the second being the one mentioned by Barrie:

> - *c*1449    R. Pecock *Repressor* (1860) 63    Therbi [thou] enhauncidist thi silf aboue thi Cristen britheren and sistren.
> - 1533    T. More *Apol*. iv, in *Wks*. 849/2    Now was this word taken vp, & walked about abrode among the brethren & sistern.
> - *a*1849    H. Coleridge *Ess. & Marginalia* (1851) I. 375    We united brethren and sisteren of the three kingdoms.
> - 1861    N. A. Woods *Tour Prince of Wales in Canada* 261    The cortège had to be eked out with the Temperance Brethren and Sistren.

### Citation

Here is the proper citation, since I have quoted so much from the entry:

> sister, n.
>
> Second edition, 1989; online version December 2011. 
>       http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/180434; accessed 04 February 2012. Earlier version first published in *New English Dictionary*, 1911.

## On *sisterns* & *cisterns*

The second form, *sistern*, I have already given as occurring under [**sister** *n*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/180434).  It also occurs in the first citation for **child**, *n.* sense 2b, where it appears under the spelling *sisterne*, with a final *e*:

> - 1382    *Bible* (Wycliffite, E.V.)  Gen. xxxvii. 30    Ruben turned aȝen to the sisterne, fonde not the child [*i.e.* Joseph æt. 17].

Note that our modern word ***cistern*** was during Middle English sometimes spelled *systerne* or *sisterne*.  Here are two citation for such, from [**cistern**, *n.*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/33469):

> - 1382    *Bible* (Wycliffite, E.V.)  Gen. xxxvii. 22    Throw ȝe him into the olde sisterne, that is in wildernes.
> - 1481–90    Howard *Househ. Bks.* (1841) 353    Paied to a carpenter for mendynge of a systern iij.d.

It is also found in citations for [**winch**, *n.<sup>1</sup>*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/229172):

> - c1440    *Pallad. on Husb.* i. 426    In stede of welle or wenche [orig. fons‥aut puteus] haue a sisterne.
> - c1440    *Pallad. on Husb.* iii. 894    The water cleer Of cisterne or of wynche.

---

## Summary

So the word has not been used for quite sometime. The only publicly visible scheduled update is under **sister**, and refers to that word’s use in the gay community; the update was entered in 1997.

However, the question on  [What is the female equivalent of brethren?](http://oxforddictionaries.com/words/what-is-the-female-equivalent-of-brethren) from Oxford Dictionaries’ online site suggests that though having long ago  fallen into disuse, that it has been recently revived:

> **Sistren**, on the other hand, had fallen completely out of use by the middle of the 16<sup>th</sup> century. It has recently been revived, typically by feminist writers, with the new meaning ‘fellow women’ (e.g. *Lead singer Beth starts out most shows with several shout-outs to her sistren*). This use is not yet well established in standard English.

I suggest that were one so inclined to do so, that one could best help re-establish the word in standard English in the easiest way possible: simply by using it.

Answer (score 4):

*Sisters*? It’s a fairly accepted word nowadays.

Comment: Hmm... it seems apt, but then Brothers would do the same that Brethren does.

Comment: It would, and, in a slightly different context, it does. I believe some orders of monks call themselves brothers.

Comment: @timonti "brethren" is the archaic word for "brothers", though. I am not sure such a word exists for "sisters".

Comment: The archaic use of *brethren* was at a time when it was taken for granted that *he* included she, *man* included women, and so on (as Churchill said, "Generally speaking, man embraces woman").  So *brethren* meant 'brothers and sisters'; I would argue that it still does, but in any case there is no 'archaic word for sisters'.

Comment: @TimLymington, although Old English *man* meant *human, person* (*wer* and *wif* were used to distinguish sexes), this was before c1300, brethren **and sistren** were both used between c1200 and c1600. So *brethren* never meant brothers and sister (any more than if you today say brothers and refer to sisters as well). Your comment is wrong on multiple levels and accounts (most of this is from etymonline.com and http://oxforddictionaries.com/page/femininebrethren)

Comment: @Unreason: While there has been a movement since the 1970's or so to make "man" refer exclusively to males, it was and is commonly used to refer to both male and female, especially in the collective or plural. You can find plenty of sources that say things like, "Man is an animal who walks upright", clearly including both male and female. Or if someone says, "I seek to live in peace with all men", he is obviously including females.  ...

Comment: (continued) It is less common today to use "man" in the singular to include both male and female, but just a few decades ago if you read, "We are looking for a man of integrity", depending on the context it might well include females.

Comment: @unreason (continued): I don't know how you can say that "brethren" doesn't and never did include women. Even today, Quakers call themselves "the brethren", and they have many female members. Bible translators today are arguing about whether the Greek word translated "brethren" in the King James should now be translated "brothers and sisters" to make clear that it includes both genders, or if this is unncessary because it is obvious. There is a lot of debate about this, but no one is saying that it always and only means males. (Some say that in some instances it only includes males, etc.)

Comment: With the risk of sounding pragmatic, it does not matter what it *used* to mean. I, personally, do not believe that *brethren* was ever intended to include females, but rather was a means of expressing male bonding. *Sisters* nowadays, to me, has a feministic connotation, but I can't think of any other word that a) will not sound overly archaic in today's language, and b) refers distinctly to females.

Comment: @Jay, you missed the main point: Tim claimed that *brethren* was used to refer to *sistren* (in Middle English) and I said it never was (it would be similar to using *brothers* in modern English to refer to both brothers and sisters). I was correcting definitively wrong statement that *sistren* as a word never existed and the argument that an Old English *man* had to do anything to do with it. So, most of your arguments miss my point. I do realize that today *man* has a meaning of 1. male human 2. member of the homo sapience spices regardless of sex; however...

Comment: see usage notes on http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/man; the problem of the 2nd meaning is that it is either potentially ambiguous or discriminatory and it is best to avoid both of these scenarios.

Comment: It matters what it used to mean when you are reading something written in the past. The meaning of a word is what it meant when it was written. The King James Bible uses "brethren" often to refer to a group including women. Like 2 Chron 28:8: "... carried away capitve of their brethren two hundred thousand women, sons, and daughters ..." "Brethren" here explicitly includes "women". Look up "gender neutral Bible" to see endless discussion of this. Google "Church of the Brethren" and you'll find numerous references to activities for "brethren women". ...

Comment: ... I understand that some people today don't like this usage and think that we should have separate words to clearly identify male-only versus mixed-gender, but what you think the word ought to mean and what other people use the word to mean are not the same thing. Especially when those people wrote long before you were born: you cannot retroactively change the definition of a word.

Comment: Jay, you fail to understan: KJV is 1604-1611; by that time even *brethren* was falling out of use. The issue of the biblical usage is very complicated, however 1) http://bible.cc/2_chronicles/28-8.htm shows that 2 Chron 28:8 does **not** refer to them all as *brethren*, instead it states that women, sons and daughters were taken from the brethren (from the males). On the other hand, you **will** find *sistren* in Wycliffe's translation (1382 to 1395; specifically he will refer to brethren and sistren) so I am hardly changing anything, I am simply trying to be precise.

Answer (score 3):

I have both Collins and Longman dictionaries, and both explain that in British English, the word *brethren* could include male and female sex in its meaning in a sentence, but there is also the word *sistren* which could be used in situations about a group with women only.

Comment: Brethren is simply a plural and the female equivalent - sistren - seems to have slipped out of usage.  Why not just 'sisters'?  BTW, thanks for enhancing my vocabulary.

Answer (score 2):

The question seems to be this, the final sentence:

> Is there some word which would refer to a closely knitted female group?

Both *sistren* and *sisteren* sound uncomfortably similar to ***cistern***. That connotes images of standing water and wooden barrels with iron clasps. Even if correct, it makes me cringe. Despite seeming gender-specific, both *brethren* AND *brothers* is preferable to an archaic word that sounds like "cistern"!

Returning to the religious theme, there is a word that refers to a closely-knit female group: **sisterhood**. That is American usage for a synagogue women's group, e.g. Hadassah Sisterhood. I've seen similar usage by Christian religious communities, Mennonite, I think.

Answer (score 2):

*Sorority* is the word you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Brethren, nowadays means any group, whether all men or both men and women, who, together are fellow members of an organization or entity. A group of all women would more appropriately be called sisters.

Comment: I'd go for sisterhood more than sisters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use kith by itself or “kith and kin”.

Comment: Please include an authoritative definition or examples of usage for how this answers the question.  Do take a moment for the site [tour] and [FAQ], and welcome.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. We're not like other Q&A sites: we're looking for *detailed and authoritative answers* supported by evidence, ideally hyperlinked to a published source. You can [edit] your post to add this extra level of detail. For further guidance, read [answer] and take the [Tour]. :-)

Answer (score -1):

"Brethren" is an obsolete word. If you are referring to a group of men, just say "brothers". If you are referring to a group of women, say "sisters". There is much debate today whether you should refer to a group of both as "brother and sisters" or whether "brothers" would be understood to include both genders.

The only reason to use "brethren" is if you want to sound old-fashioned. Or, I suppose, if you are writing an historical novel. Some people like to use these obsolete words in a religious context, like referring to God with "thee" and "thou" and talking about members of the church as "the brethren", that somehow these obsolete words are "more spiritual" or something. Personally I don't see the point of this, but that's another subject.

Comment: Brethren is an archaic plural of brother and is no longer used with its original, primary meaning.  However, it is clearly still in contemporary use, picking up 1117 hits on [COCA](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/) so cannot be described as obsolete.

Comment: Okay, perhaps "obsolete" is the wrong word. "Archaic" is more accurate.